# Could not find or load main class - VS Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I created a new java project (with the option `Create Java Project`), and 
When I click the run button (marked with the red circle), it gives me the error `Could not find or load main class`.

When I run the program from the `run` option above the `main`(marked with the green circle), it works and doesn't show me the error.

How can I fix it?

[image: The project]

This is the `.classpath` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: whats your full app class name space? like `com.acme.example.ListAppuals`

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen Where can I find the namespace?

Comment: Where did you get that run button in the upper right corner, it's not part of the standard Visual Studio Code as far as I can see? Some extension you installed? Since standard 'Run' works maybe you should just ignore that button?

Comment: Seems to not be your case, but I had the same problem because of special characters in the source's path.

Answer (score 92):

This is a known issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug/issues/606, https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ls/issues/1137, which caused the new package not recognized during building workspace. It's expected to be fixed in vscode-java Middle October release.

Current workaround is **reload VS Code window**, or **F1 ->Clean the java language server workspace**.

Comment: upvote for  `F1 ->Clean the java language server workspace`.

Comment: I don't know if this will help anybody, but I had this problem because my class with the main method didn't have the .java file extension. Renaming the file allowed the compiler to start working. This was misleading because the file was detected and a maroon "J" icon decorated the file in the project listing pane.

Answer (score 17):

i think you install the **Code Runner** Extension,so you have a `Run` icon in the upper right-hand corner，you could try to uninstall it,

then **F1 ->Clean the java language server workspace.**,run your code with `F5` or the `Run` above your `Main` method

Comment: Yes, I installed **Code Runner**, In order to run C programs.

Comment: I also encountered the same issue with CodeRunner, that seems to be the package name（app） of your class if you configure it in the `setting.json` file like `"java":"cd $dir && javac -d . $fileName  && java app.$fileNameWithoutExt"`,it would work

Comment: Code Runner is the problem I think, Your answer worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Pressing `ctrl+f5` solves the problem.

[image]

Terminal output:

```
PS F:\Testing>  & 'c:\Users\xyz\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.34.0\scripts\launcher.bat' 'C:\jdk-18\bin\java.exe' '-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages' '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' '-cp' 'C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\1edb6264f8da6da9dda20a68800df89b\redhat.java\jdt_ws\Testing_e004a758\bin' 'mypackage.Foo'
hello
```

Answer (score 2):

Install `java` extension package and try running it by `CTRL` + `F5`. Works well by the time it gets fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try editing your .classpath file to show it where your main class is.

An easier, but much more jank method, is to move your .java file to the root of your project directory to help vscode find it.

Comment: I added the .classpath file. What do I need to change in it?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I added the `launch.json` in the project, and modified the default configs from ${file} like this:
[image]

then I started debugging and it worked as usual.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the solutions worked, **simply re-build your project to generate updated `.class`** file for the class that contains the main method.

Basically, this error means that Java compiler was unable to find the proper `.class` file, and your source `.java` has a main method that wasn't added to the compiled `.class` yet.

This can be the case mainly for Maven projects.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there was still having the same issue. My solution was to compile the code from the command line. This made the .class file for me, and then I was able to run my code. Probably better solutions out there but that's what I did

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because there isn't a 'Main' Class, and the compiler is looking for that specific class, might be an issue with the project manager naming the class App instead of 'Main', a quick fix ***might*** be to name the Class 'Main' and see if that works instead.

Answer (score 0):

The same happened for me but it was easy fix,
Check the launch.json if the class name is correct

Since I changed the group of my class.

Check wheter your launch.json file data is correct.
Since sometimes launch.json does not auto-update.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above works for you, check your folder/file name. See if there is any non-English naming.

My issue was I can compile and run the program with no problem in terminal, but got the error when running in VScode. Solve the problem by renaming my file path from `/Documents/算法/App.java` to `/Documents/Algo/App.java`

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that the project's folder name had some Persian/Arabic characters in it. After I renamed the folder, everything started to working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I get the same error when I am debugging a multi-module maven project. It seems that the `classpath` is not set automatically or not set correctly when you try t debug without using a launch config. You need to define a `lunch` request in the `launch.json` file and set the `classpath` to point to the correct `jar` files. You must build the project using `mvn install` to generate the required jar files for the project which are defined in `pom.xml' for all modules. I tried to set the classpath to point to the generated` *.class` binary files but it didn't work I think because I need to specify each and everyone which wasn't possible.

To ensure you are using the correct config, first, find out the command line details using `java.exe` which is required to run your application, and then configure this command using the `launch.json` file.

Also, configure the `console` of the `debug` session to be the `integrated terminal`  and lunch the debug with or without the `launch.json' file. Then start the debug and watch out for the generated commands and you can find what is wrong by analyzing the commands used to launch the application.

Below is an example of a config item in `launch.json' file:

```
        {
            "name": "Java",
            "type": "java",
            "request": "launch",
            "classPaths": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/",
                "${workspaceFolder}/path/to/jar",
                "${workspaceFolder}/path/to/jar",
                ...
            ],
            "mainClass": "com.startup.class.name",
            "projectName": "project name",
            "vmArgs": [
                "-Xms64m -Xmx950m"
            ],

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it is resolved by ensuring the installed jdk on my machine matches with the java.version in the pom.xml.

```
<properties>
    <java.version>20.0.1</java.version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue on VSCode on macOS.

Renaming the extension to all small resolved my issue.

FileName.***J***ava to FileName.***j***ava

Answer (score 0):

Check if you haven't made your **main() method static**. The "*Static*" key word says that the method belongs to this class itself. If you haven't made you main() *static* then it will be confused between all classes of the same program/directory/workspace, especially in vscode editor workspace.
if it still doesn't works, relode vs code window or clean your workspace by pressing **f1** followed by typing **clean java language server workspace.**

Answer (score 0):

[Error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ky6gO.png)

[Answer]
Save the java file by ctrl+s and then compile and run the code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

try deleting the .vscode folder and run it again

Comment: This does not explain what the problem is and why the answer would solve the problem.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score -2):

Create a file `settings.json` inside the `.vscode` folder of your application and add below configuration.

```
"java.configuration.updateBuildConfiguration": "automatic"
```